# Handling 300 field form in the database

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm dealing with an enormous online form right now.  It's separated into different sections visually, but those tend to change.  With around 300 fields, it almost seems ridiculous to put them into a single table, though if I separate them and someone decides to move a field to a different section on the front end on several different occasions, it will become a mess in the database and fields won't match their front end sections.

I'm essentially asking: ***What is the best way to organize something like this in a normalized fashion?***

Comment: Do you need a seperate database column for each of the form fields? Perhaps you could serialize the not so important ones and store them in one column then only.

Comment: I don't think I will ever serialize data into a database, not how I roll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the field names to another table and reference them in the value table.

Example

```
field_id   | field_name
------------------------
1          | first_name
2          | last_name
```

Then reference from the values:

```
value_id  | field_id   | value
--------------------------------
1         | 1          | John
2         | 2          | Doe
3         | 1          | Max
4         | 2          | Jefferson
```

Comment: It's called Entity-Attribute-Value model (EAV). Great for writes, terrible for number crunching the data stored in such a way.

Comment: See, this is where I was going with it at the moment. I had just whiteboarded this, heh +1

Comment: Though EAV can be a bit of a burden, would throwing this all in one table be just..pure crap?  It seems like the path of least resistance at this point without much of a downside in comparison.

Comment: Sticking all the data in a single table = nightmare. Personally, I'd use a hybrid approach between EAV and regular SQL. Volatile info into EAV, info required for various reports and what not into regular SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a SQL database, then the Entity-Attribute-Value model (EAV) described above is probably a good answer.  You might also want to mix in a couple of denormalized tables with common or specialized data.

Another option might be a document store though; this sounds like just the kind of problem that inspired data stores like MongoDB.  In MongoDB you just store everything as a giant json document.  If some data isn't needed for some records and is left out, it isn't considered "bad" in the way sparsely populated wide SQL database tables are.

Comment: Doing contract work - they have me pretty locked into their technologies.  Though I agree, EAV (even though I had no idea what that was when I was modeling it out) seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your fields. Separate them as components and you will probably notice, that you can make multiple tables out off that one. Also by separating table you cant make form with, for example:

- fieldset tags
- separate it in multiple steps (it think the best solution)
- multiple ajax requests for each form after previous is filled
- form separated by open/close javascript windows

Comment: Well see, that's how I originally set it up, essentially.  The problem being - Management now wants an item from step 1 on step 3, and then my database begins to mismatch from the front end form - which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Database design, object design, and form design are three very different elements.  If there are relationships between the data in a one to may fashion, you should have different tables to normalize the data.  If however, everything is a One-to-one relationship then having all 300 in the same table is perfectly acceptable.  I find it difficult to believe that there is a logical or even physical construct that has 300 elements unto itself; but it's possible. If you start getting into attribute data of something lets say we're talking about a vehicle.  We could be talking about a car, a truck, a semi, a motorcycle, a bicycle, etc... each of those types of vehicles have different properties which would be managed in separate tables to normalize the data. moving elements of them to different pages wouldn't make a whole lot of sense; but moving common attributes might.  For example I wouldn't ask about color on section 1 and again in section 4.  But I might section things out to describe make, model, and then custom attributes.